# Loop through table data and compare using split

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables and i need to compare data and update/insert one table records. What iam trying to do is I need to take each record from Table1, 
use a split function then for each text in split, compare dataelement field between both these tables. We are syncing data in Table2 to similar to Table1.
Please let me know how this can be done. I am ok using cursor or merge. This is the scenario

```
DataTable:

dataId    dataelement
1           Check
2           System
3           Balances
4           City
5           State
6           Zip
7           Other


Table1:

Id    reqId      dataelementValues
1       52       Check
2       52       City;State;System
3       52       Other

Table2:

elId  dataId   dataelement reqId Active
1      6          Zip        52    1
2      1          Check      52    1
3      4          city       52    1
4      5          State      52    1
```

Outcome Should be similar to after compare in table2

```
Table2:

elId  dataId   dataelement reqId Active
1      6          Zip        52    0 (Should be set to inactive as it exists in table2 but not in table1)
2      1          Check      52    1 (NO Updates as it exists in both the tables) 
3      4          city       52    1 (NO Updates as it exists in both the tables) 
4      5          State      52    1 (NO Updates as it exists in both the tables) 

5      2          System     52    1 (Get the dataid for system from datatable and insert in table2 as it exists in table1 but not in table2) 
6      7          Other      52    1 (Get the dataid for other  from datatable and insert in table2 as it exists in table1 but not in table2)
```

This is where iam at, not sure how to set inactive on table2.

```
WHILE Exists(Select * from #Table1)      
     BEGIN            
            Select @currentId = Id, @dataValue = dataelementValues FROM #Table1 where rowID=(SELECT top 1 rowID from #Table1 order by rowID asc) 


           SET @pos = 0
           SET @len = 0
           WHILE CHARINDEX(';', @dataValue, @pos+1)>0
            BEGIN               
                SET @dataValueValue = SUBSTRING(@dataValue, @pos, CHARINDEX('|', @dataValue, @pos+1) - @pos)               
                SET @glbaDEId = (Select DataTable.dataId  from datatable where dataelement = @dataValue)                     

                IF NOT Exists (Select * from #Table2  Where DataElement=@dataValue)
                   BEGIN                   
                      --Insert into table2
                    END             

                 SET @pos = CHARINDEX('|', @dataValue, @pos+@len) +1
                END

           DELETE from #Table1 where rowID=(SELECT top 1 rowID from #Table1 order by rowID asc )   
      END
```

Comment: You certainly don't need a cursor or any other kind of looping here. Unfortunately as posted there isn't enough detail for me to wrap my brain around what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to compare table1 data to table2 based on text field data element. If both are same i dont need to do anything. If exists in table1 and not in table2 insert it. If exists in table2 and not in table1 make it inactive.

Comment: Seems to me this can be accomplished using outer joins with a like operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a MERGE statement with a few other tricks.

[Merge Guide](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/)

```
-- Create a CTE that will split out the combined column and join to DataTable 
-- to get the dataId
;WITH cteTable1Split AS
(
    SELECT reqId, dt.* FROM
    (  
        SELECT 
            [dataelement] = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)'),
            reqId
        FROM 
        ( 
            -- use xml to split column 
            -- http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings
            SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
                + REPLACE([dataelementValues], ';', '</i><i>') 
                + '</i>').query('.'),
                   reqId
            FROM Table1
        ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
    ) a
    JOIN DataTable dt ON dt.[dataelement] = a.[dataelement]
)
-- Merge Table2 with the CTE
MERGE INTO Table2 AS Target
USING cteTable1Split AS Source 
ON Target.[dataelement] = Source.[dataelement]

-- If exists in Target (Table2) but not Source (CTE) then UPDATE Active flag
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source THEN
UPDATE SET ACTIVE = 0

-- If exists in Source (CTE) but not Target (Table2) then INSERT new record
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT ([dataId], [dataelement], [reqId], [Active]) 
VALUES (SOURCE.[dataId], SOURCE.[dataelement], SOURCE.[reqId], 1);
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5032/1)

Comment: Thanks for creating sql fiddle and for query in detail. I still need to make few changes to suit my scenarios but this helps immensely.

Answer (score 0):

You've not mentioned whether you have control over the structure of these tables, so I'm going to go ahead and suggest you **redesign Table1 to normalise the dataelementValues column**.

That is, instead of this:

```
Table1:

Id    reqId      dataelementValues
1       52       Check
2       52       City;State;System
3       52       Other
```

You should be storing this:

```
Table1_New:

Id    reqId      dataelementValues
1       52       Check
2       52       City
2       52       State
2       52       System
3       52       Other
```

You may also need a new, surrogate, primary key column on the table, using an `IDENTITY(1,1)` specification.

Storing your data like this is how relational databases are intended to be used/designed. As well as simplifying the problem at hand right now, you might find it removes potential problems in the future as well.

Comment: I wish I had the control we cant restructure tables, I tried to convince but it seems not working.

Answer (score 0):

The main challenge here is creating a rowset with the dataelementValues correctly split into separate rows. The accepted answer shows clearly how this can be used as the `source` for a `merge` statement to achieve the update and insert operation.

However, there are alternative ways to create the split or normalised rowset.

One way, which I personally prefer for clarity over resorting to xml in this particular case, is a `like join`. This takes advantage of the fact that you already have the separate rows you need in `DataTable`, just not with all the columns you need.

```
Select DT.dataId, DT.dataelement, T1.reqid
From Table1 T1
Inner join DataTable DT
On T1.dataelementValues like '%' + DT.dataelement + '%'
```

I've not been able to test this right now but should give the rowset you need, because the like operator causes one T1 row to match three times to the corresponding DT rows.

Comment: NB, this approach does have limitations, for example if you had two separate data elements 'zip' and 'zipcode', the like join would incorrectly match 'zip' to both.